# Javascript - Give first X divs other class

Tags: javascript

I have a webshop with filters on the left side which are all open. What is need is to open only the first 4 divs (they have a class "active") and the others should have a class "inactive"

I have already the code to toggle the element if it has class "active" it will toggle to "inactive" when you click it and the way around.

```
$(".av-filter-wrapper").off();
    $(".av-filter-wrapper").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        self.toggleFilter($(this));
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just loop over all elements on startup and give them the classes depending on the index in the loop like so:

```
$(".av-filter-wrapper").each((index, el) => {
    if(index <= 4)
        el.classList.add('active');
    else
        el.classList.add('inactive');
});
```

Or with pure JavaScript:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.av-filter-wrapper').forEach((el, index) => {
    if(index <= 4)
        el.classList.add('active');
    else
        el.classList.add('inactive');
});
```

Comment: I used to think it's `.each()` in jQuery - or is it just a normal array?